# How can I get a message from a specific contact?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, whatsapp

I'd like to retrieve a message from a contact on Whats App (with user's permission, of course, I thought something like oAuth) but as far I found, what apps doesn't have an API. So I tried load the web version in a WebBrowser and get the messag from there but I can't make it work.

It start loading the page to request the Qr code to be scanned but it redirects to a page saying the current browser isn't supported. So I tried to use emulation mode on IE, setting it to IE11 and changing http user agent to proper IE11's but it doesn't work either. How can I fix this?

Here's my current code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(
           int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

        const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
        const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH = 0x10000002;
        const string usersAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetEmulation();
            ChangeUserAgent(usersAgent);
        }

        public static void ChangeUserAgent(string UserAgent)
        {
            UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, null, 0, 0);
            UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, UserAgent, UserAgent.Length, 0);
        }

        public void SetEmulation()
        {
            const int BROWSER_EMULATION_IE11 = 0x2AF9;  
            var appName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                             appName, BROWSER_EMULATION_IE11, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

        void UnsetEmulation()
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true))
            {
                var appName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
                key.DeleteValue(appName);
            }
        }
}
```

and I try open like this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

AA totally different solution to accomplish this is very welcome.

Comment: I'm on the way to make it wor k with Cef browser... I give up on .NET's native web browser

Comment: If you browse using IE11 you will see supported browsers in the home page. *We recommend using WhatsApp with one of the following browsers: Google Chrome , Mozilla Firefox,  Opera WhatsApp also supports: Microsoft Edge, Safari (MacOS 10.8+ Only)* It seems the site doesn't support IE at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browse https://web.whatsapp.com/ using Internet Explorer you will see supported browsers in the home page which says:

> We recommend using WhatsApp with one of the following browsers:
>
> - Google Chrome
> - Mozilla Firefox
> - Opera WhatsApp
>
> also supports:
>
> - Microsoft Edge
> - Safari (MacOS 10.8+ Only)

So it seems currently the site doesn't support Internet Explorer .As an alternative you can use [Cefsharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) browser. To do so, install a suitable [CefSharp.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/) nuget package into visual studio and then add the control to your form and run the application:

```
var browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

After you run the program, it shows a QR code which if you scan using your phone you will be logged in.

To scan the QR code, you should have WhatsApp installed on your mobile. Then open the application → CHATS → Open menu → Choose WhatApp Web then scan the code.

Comment: **Note 1:** The latest version of `CefSharp.WinForms` (at the moment 53.0.0) needs .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: **Note 2:** It doesn't work with `Any CPU` platform setting out of the box. You should choose `x86` or `x64`. To have Any CPU support take a look at [Feature Request - Add AnyCPU Support #1714](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714)

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: While I managed to make it work with Cef browser at time I said on comments, I'll accept your answer anyway. Thanks