# How can I access Whatsapp Web from WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, whatsapp

Im trying to access Whatsapp Web from my desktop application using a WebBrowser Control, but a message popups, recommending me to use Chrome, Firefox, etc..

How can I avoid this message and get the QR Code? I tried changing the User-Agent this way:

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);
const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36";
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, userAgent, userAgent.Length, 0);
}
```

But it didn't work. I mean, it changed the User-Agent, but I'm still getting the same message.

I check current User-Agent using this web: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

What can I do? Thanks in advice!

Comment: [How can I get a message from a specific contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774833/3110834)

Comment: If you browse https://web.whatsapp.com/ using Internet Explorer you will see supported browsers in the home page which says:
*We recommend using WhatsApp with one of the following browsers: Google Chrome,Mozilla Firefox and Opera.  WhatsApp also supports: Microsoft Edge, Safari (MacOS 10.8+ Only)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native WebBrowser control is based on Internet Explorer, which, when embedded, runs in IE7 compatibility mode by Default. 
IE is used regardless of the default browser on your system.
Whatsapp Web seems to support no version of IE, so it makes no sense to alter the compatibility mode of the WebBrowser control.

Instead, you should consider using a different browser control, like Chromium.
There are a lot of resources on the web about how to integrate Chromium into a .Net application.